# How can I enter download mode on LG Doubleplay?

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, lg-doubleplay

How can I enter download mode on LG Doubleplay (C729)?

None of the regular key combinations seem to work, not even 'adb reboot download' - it just reboots the phone.

I know that this is quite specific, but it would certainly help many LG Doubleplay users.

Thanks!